# Метод для удаления повторяющихся символов в строке

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь удалить повторяющиеся символы в строке.

```
public static string dist(string a, string b)
{
    string conc = a + b;
    string str = conc.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToString();
    return str;
}
```

При вызове `Console.WriteLine(dist("hello","world"));` получаю:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+DistinctIterator`1[System.Char]

Обьясните пожалуйста, почему я получаю это, и как получить строку?

Comment: `string str = string.Concat(conc.Distinct());`